# Chern-Weil theory in the cohomological Atiyah-Singer theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes, k-theory

I am interested in the following piece of data appearing in the cohomological Atiyah-Singer theorem. My reference is "The index of elliptic operators. III" by Atiyah and Singer.

Let $D:\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(F)$ be an elliptic operator where $E\to X$ and $F\to X$ are complex vector bundles over a closed manifold $X$. The principal symbol of $D$ is a bundle isomorphism $\pi^\ast E\to\pi^\ast F$, where $\pi$ is the restriction of the projection $T^\ast X\to X$ to the complement of the zero section.

Given a Riemannian metric on $X$, the Thom space $\operatorname{Th}_X$ of $T^\ast X\to X$ is the topological space arising as the one-point compactification of the unit ball subbundle of $T^\ast X$. Using the above bundle isomorphism (and the obvious extension across the zero section), one extends $\pi^\ast E-\pi^\ast F$ to an element of $K(\operatorname{Th}_X)$. The Chern character gives an element of cohomology on the Thom space, and the cohomological Thom isomorphism gives an element of cohomology on $X$.

Now, the de Rham theorem says that this final cohomology element can be represented by a smooth differential form.

My question is:

- can such a smooth form be prescribed in differential-geometric terms from the principal symbol, the (choice of) Riemannian metric on $X$, and perhaps a choice of hermitian bundle metrics and metric-compatible connections on $E\to X$ and $F\to X$?

This seems non-obvious since the Thom space does not seem to have a natural smooth structure, and so the use of the Chern character in the above presentation doesn't seem immediately amenable to the Chern-Weil approach. But, given the context and the conclusion, it seems unnatural to be forced to reach into the theory of topological characteristic classes.

If I understand correctly, the answer to my question is "essentially yes" according to Quillen's article "Superconnections and the Chern character," which identifies such a differential form via a choice of "superconnection" on $\pi^\ast E\oplus\pi^\ast F.$ However, Quillen's article seems to be answering a more general question, and has nothing to do with, for instance, the Thom space. Can one make use of the more special situation above to give a simpler answer than Quillen's?